# [Flow]Using decorator @connect: Property not found in props of React element

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

#### Child1.js

```
// @flow
type Props = {
  prop1: string,
}
class Child1 extends Component<void, Props, void> {
  ...
}
export default connect(state -> state.child1)(Child1);
```

#### Child2.js

```
// @flow
type Props = {
  prop1: string,
}
@connect(state => state.child2)
export default class Child2 extends Component<void, Props, void> {
  ...
}
```

#### Parent.js

```
// @flow
export default class Parent extends Component<void, void, void> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child1 /> // no flow error
        <Child2 /> // flow error: property 'props1' property not found in props of React element Child2
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I had already added `esproposal.decorators=ignore` to .flowconfig -> [options].

How can I solve the flow error above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Workaround

#### Child2.js

```
// @flow
type Props = {
  dispatch: Function,
  prop: string,
}

type DefaultProps = Props;

@connect(state => state.child2)
export default class Banner extends React.Component<DefaultProps, Props, void> {
  static defaultProps = {
    dispatch: () => {},
    prop: '',
  }
  ...
}
```

Then in Parent.js, Child2 doesn't bring any flow-errors.

Honestly, DefaultProps is kinda unnecessary for me... **I'm not gonna close this issue unless there are more convenient/general solution.**